# How should I name model field when natural name is ruby/rails keyword?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, naming-conventions

I had similar problem and it is recurs over and over again. How to name model field when our best idea for it is already a keyword in ruby or rails?

For example I have model named Task and I want to have boolean field named public or private. Interesting fact is that I can do it, although public and private are words used in ruby classes. I can change the name to public_task or private_task, but then I have for example task.public_task which does not look good.

Another example is when I want to name boolean field default and give it default value true/false.
Then I have in migration file:

```
add_column :tasks, :default, :boolean, default: true
```

What should I do in similar situations? Should I use these words, add another word or it is better to look for less meaningfull synonyms?

Comment: In my opinion you should stay away from all words/keywords that have a predefined meaning, whether some of them will work or not. It just adds confusion later on.

Answer (score 2):

Neither `private` nor `public` nor `default` column names will cause you programmatic problems.

<s>The only thing it will cause is confusion :)</s>

You won't be able to define scopes, say the following will result in exception:

```
class MyClass < ApplicationRecord
  scope :private, -> { where(private: :some_value) }
end

#=> ArgumentError: You tried to define a scope named "private" on the model "MyClass", but Active Record already defined a class method with the same name.
```

Convention *is* of course *over* configuration, and I wouldn't go with using these as column names, but if you and your project team can't pick better names and decide to do so despite potential difficulties related to avoiding things like above - this won't hurt anyone. Not programmatically leastwise.

Comment: Finally, argument. Actually, I think that there are more broken cases, so the best idea is to turn your fantasy on and just don't use ruby keywords.